Baking Specular Maps for Unity
how do I correctly bake a Specular Map for Unity's Standard Shader (Specular Setup)?
I know that a Specular Map for Unity is the Color of the reflection. For my project I need to control both reflectivity and roughness.
Therefore, I chose the Unity's Specular Shader.

"Correctly" how? Are you asking what the process behind baking a specular map is, or what a proper specular map looks like?

How to tell blender, to bake a specular map.
Which results in the same outcome in unity's standard specular shader

Blender uses metalness and roughness. You would need to convert the maps and bake as the Emit bake type. The conversion can be done inside the shader. The specular map will be the Base Color input that uses Metallic input as a mask, so only metallic parts are present and the rest is a dark color range for the dielectrics. The specular workflow's diffuse map is the Base Color with black in the metallic parts. The glossiness is an inverted roughness.
The Blender's Specular value is related but not the same as  the Specular PBR, it has been renamed to IOR Level under the Specular section in the newer Blender versions.



This is very close to what I'm currently using.
I multiply the specular IOR with a very Dark color for non-metals, which I've I got via stepwise approximation.
I've also tried making my own shader in Unity that can use roughness and specular information (like in Blender). I multiply the specular (from Blender) with 0.1. The result is very close to blenders preview.
